# Testing own implementation of a semaphore

Tags: c#, .net, thread-safety, semaphore

In my Unity project I need to use a semaphore for limiting the amount of threads that can access a resource.

The only problem though, it's that for "security reasons", the Unity web player doesn't allow you to instantiate C# standard semaphore, System.Threading.Semaphore (they say it's because you can hang up the browser with semaphores....)

So my solution to that is to implement my own semaphore with System.Threading.Monitor class, which it is available in the web player. Ironic, because making my own implementation of the semaphore it's less safer than using the c#'s standard.

```
private object _lock;
private int max;
private int count;

public MySemaphore(int maximumCount)
{
    _lock = new object();
    max = maximumCount;
    count = 0;
}

public void WaitOne()
{
    bool green = false;

    bool haveLock = false;
    try
    {
        Monitor.Enter(_lock); // Get the lock
        haveLock = true; // Monitor.Enter should have a 2nd parameter to make this operation atomic. Dammit unity...
        while(!green)
        {
            if(count < max)
            {
                count++;
                green = true;
            }else if(count == max){
                Monitor.Wait(_lock); // Release the lock and wait for a change. Then reaquire the lock
            }else{
                Debug.LogWarning("Semaphore broken."); // This should not be called. If it is, the semaphore is broken. Threading is hard...
                Monitor.Wait(_lock);
            }
        }
    } finally {
        if(haveLock) Monitor.Exit(_lock); // Release the lock
    }
}

public void Release()
{
    bool haveLock = false;
    try
    {
        Monitor.Enter(_lock); // Get the lock
        haveLock = true;
        count--;
        Monitor.PulseAll(_lock); // Send a signal to everyone waiting that the count has been decreased.
    } finally {
        if(haveLock) Monitor.Exit(_lock); // Release the lock
    }
}
```

Is there anyway to test that this class is thread-safe? Or if anyone has some experience with thread stuff, can he tell me please if this is safe?.

Comment: Replace `Monitor.Enter` and `Monitor.Exit` with lock statement to get rid of the `try {} finally {}` and `haveLock`. Otherwise it seems ok to me.

Comment: Second TomT's comment, plus make _lock a private STATIC object.

Comment: @simonatrcl Why static? What if OP wants to have several semaphore instances? Maybe you meant `readonly`?

Comment: I did mean static (although readonly is applicable). I was thinking of protecting the area for multiple instances of the class.

Comment: Thank you very much for all feedback. I didn't know you could combine lock statement with Monitor.Wait and Monitor.Pulse. Also making it readonly looks more safe, and static will work in my case, since I have only one semaphore. I think that if i had more than one semaphore I'd get more locks than I really need...